# Combo loses focus on typing

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

My combo uses remote query. When the user types something, the server returns matching results. However, when there are a lot of matching results, then the combo expands, loses focus and highlights the firts record returned by the server. The combo has these properties:

```
...
queryMode:'remote',
enableKeyEvents:true,
forceSelection:true,
...
```

The screen of what is going on is here:

[image]

So, as you can see, when the user typed the last character, the server returned records and for some (I think stupid) reason highlighted the first record. But what is more important there is no focus any longer and the user has to put cursor on the field again to continue typing. To solve this problem, I tried these events:

```
 'blur':function(){
    this.focus();
  },
  'keydown':function(){
    this.focus();
  },
  'keypress':function(){
    this.focus();
  },
  'keyup':function(){
    this.focus();
  },
```

But there is no effect. I also tried to use load event, but it also has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, for solve it use the afterQuery property in the combo.
Something like this:

```
afterQuery: function() {
    combo.setRawValue(combo.lastQuery);
    },
```

pd: I think this is a Bug, but i'm not sure about it...

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the similar issue with focus be two actions:

1. Set "selectOnFocus: false"
2. Update doRawQuery. 
   doRawQuery: function() {
       var me = this;

...
        me.inputEl.focus(); 
    }

If you have your overridden version (I believe you should to not change original plugin), you can do it this way to not duplicate the logic:
doRawQuery: function() {
        var me = this;

```
    me.callParent(arguments);
    me.inputEl.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xtype: 'combo',
...
listeners:{
        // repair raw value after blur
        blur:function() {
            var val = this.getRawValue();
            this.setRawValue.defer(1, this, [val]);
        }
}
```

---

[Look this example(thanks to Saki)](http://examples.extjs.eu/?ex=combo)

Comment: Thank you, sir! Demo looks promising. Now I will check my app and report back.

Comment: Unfortunately, this example does not work in extjs 4.1, which I tagged my question with